# MS Access How to make a field in form invisible if it is empty

Tags: sql, null, visibility

I am trying to make a filed in my form become invisible if it's value is empty.

What I have is a form with individual records from a table, this has a sub-form which is linked by an ID, and it displays the results of a query.

This has three fields ones is the ID, a number and third is a date, Not all records have a date and therefore for the ones that do not have one I want to completely hide the date label and the empty text box; and make it appear only when a date is specified.

I'm guessing I might have to use some kind of WHILE statement in my query but I'm not sure whether that's right and how to do it.

I would appreciate your advice on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to the subform current event:

```
If (datafieldname & "") = "" then
    datafieldname.visible=false
else
    datafieldname.visible=true
End if
```

Where datafieldname is the name of the data field on the subform. This will only work if your subform layout is not tableview